# Divs height problem

Tags: css

How to get that div id="left"  has height equal like divs right_up and right_down together ?

```
    <div style="width: 1050px;">
    <div id="left" style="width: 80%;height:80%;min-height: 80%;float: left; background-color: blueviolet;">a</div>
    <div id="right_up" style="width: 20%;height:40%;min-height: 40%; float: left; background-color: yellow;">
        <p>some text using paragraphs</p><p>some text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>some text using lists</li>
            <li>some text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="right_down" style="width: 20%;min-height: 40%;height:40%; float: left; background-color: aqua; margin-left: 80%;">
        <p>some text using paragraphs</p><p>some text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>some text using lists</li>
            <li>some text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh man, that inline css is killing me

Comment: Use tables, they are the simplest and the most reliable when it comes to table-like layouts.

Comment: Tables are unnecessary. This layout is pretty simple, and just needs a background image on the container div to give the illusion of equal height.

Comment: I cannot use image, I need to set bottom, left and top border on div left and to set left, bottom right border  on div right_down and right and top border on div right_up, to look like table ( just div left like rowspan =2 )

Answer (score 1):

to me works removing

```
margin-left: 80%;
```

from div id="right_down"

Comment: firefox and chrome, right now i cannot test it on IE bucause i'm on a ubuntu machine

Comment: I tried your solution in  mozilla and chrome. It doesn't work .

Comment: It works for 2 other people, but not you? I'm guessing you have some other CSS that's interfering.

Answer (score 1):

[Cheat.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**
-- Fix: Using `XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD`
-- Fix: Background fills to height of `div#wrapper`
-- Broke: No longer adjusts to browser height

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>div-height</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<style type="text/css">
    div#wrapper {
        width: 1050px;
        height: 80%;
        min-height: 80%;
        background-color: blueviolet;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    div#left {
        width: 80%;
        float: left;
    }
    div#right_up, div#right_down {
        width: 20%;
        height: 40%;
        min-height: 40%;
        float: right;
    }
    div#right_up {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    div#right_down {
        clear: right;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    div.clearfix {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">a</div>
    <div id="right_up">
        <p>some text using paragraphs</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>some text using lists</li>
            <li>some text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="right_down">
        <p>some text using paragraphs</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>some text using lists</li>
            <li>some text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this .css make the div#left full height?

Comment: @ghoppe: no idea, the only thing I did was separate the CSS from the HTML.

Comment: This is what I need ! Can you give me please all html ?

Comment: Problem is when i put tags like doctype, html and head, then is different ! Do I need that tags, for load jquery and other javascript ? 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: @ jnpcl Maybe I put wrong DTD ? In chrome and mozilla and chrome looks fine without doctyoe, but with doctype doesn't. In explorer doesn't look at all ok. Any help, pls ?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work with the `DOCTYPE` set to `XHTML 1.0 Strict`. I'll try to find a fix.